# 'live update' a form field with php

Tags: php, forms, auto-update

If I had the very basic form;

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'input1' value = '2'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'input2'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'answer'>
```

Is there a way with php that I can have the `answer` box be 'live' so that immediately after I put 10 second box it displays `20` as a value?

I'm familiar with how I could do this with a submit. My goal however is to not have to refresh the page

To give a slightly more detailed form:

calculate volume of prism based on set value, and user input for length

```
$sideOfSquare;
echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'input1'>";
ehco "<input type = 'text' name = 'squareSide' value ='.$sideOfSquare.'>;
echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'answer' value = 'INPUT1 * $sideOfSqaure * $sideOfSquare'>;
```

Comment: @EdwinAlex i've never worked with ajax before. Would that be relatively simple and do you by chance have a link to a tutorial or something of the like?

Comment: You can do this with javascript if the function to calculate the answer is actually that simple,  or was that just an example?

Comment: If you need to use ajax, jQuery makes it very easy. Tut here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: @mhopkins321 Sorry. It can be done in Jquery itself. Find the answer below

Comment: @popnoodles I've pulled all the data from the db into the php page. So all the data resides in `$variables`. Is it still that easy?

Comment: Only if the answer to my question is yes @EdwinAlex

Comment: It's to calculate volume of prism so this is something that doesn't need PHP to do, js can manage this.

Comment: @mhopkins321 yes if the data is on the page it's a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in Jquery also

```
$("#input2").keyup(function() {
   var input2 = $(this).val();
   var answer = parseInt(input2) * parseInt($("#input1").val());

   $("#answer").val(answer);    

});
```

Make sure about two things.

1) You should keep these id's in appropriate text boxes.

2) Validate inputs to get numeric values only

Comment: I replied to your comment. The above example is simplified. But not by much. I have used php to pull all the data from the db. I will modify my question

Comment: I could copy paste this, and substitue `input1`, `input2` and `answer` with my variable names, however that wont really help me understand what's going on and how to use this in the future. If you dont mind me asking, 1.) does this go within the `<?php` tags? 2.) for `#answer` how do I reference this value in the form? 3.) does this text need to come before or after where the data is (ie head, begining of body, end of body). Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use jQuery ajax to do what you want in PHP:
( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ )

```
// current file
$("#input2").keyup(function() {
    var input2 = $(this).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'myfile.php?input2=' + input2
    }).done(function( data ){
        $(this).val(data);
    });

});


 // myfile.php
 <?php $input2 = $_GET['input2'];
 echo $input2*2; //what you echo here will be sent to data in the success function above.
```

Comment: I could copy paste this, and substitue `input1`, `input2` and `answer` with my variable names, however that wont really help me understand what's going on and how to use this in the future. If you dont mind me asking, 1.) does this go within the `<?php` tags? 2.) for `#answer` how do I reference this value in the form? 3.) does this text need to come before or after where the data is (ie head, begining of body, end of body)? 4.) you have `current file` and `myFile`. Is there a reason to not contain everything int he same file? will it still be 'live'? Thanks in advance for your help